# Reading Different Channels Sequentially Using SPI

Tags: gpio, serial, spi, pigpio

Background: I am trying to make transfer measurements from an ADC LTC1867 to my raspberry pi using SPI. I get it to work with one channel. The ADC has 8 channels, I have one channel connected to a 2.5V reference and one connected to ground. The ADC reads them when I only call spi.xfer2 once in my code.

I want to use the 2.5V reference channel to determine any offset or gain errors to correct my actual reading. However, in my code

```
def ReadChannel(channel):
  #Performs an SPI transaction.
  #Chip-select should be held active between blocks.
  #pi.spi_xfer([XXXXXXX,0])#sends 2 bytes 1st contains DIN, second is irrelevant
  #pin 7-GND=[244,0] connected to ground
  #pin 6-GND=[180,0] connected to 2.5V

  spi.close()
  spi.open(0,0)
  spi.max_speed_hz = 10000 
  channel_six = spi.xfer2([244,0])
  print channel_six
  spi.close()

  sleep(0.005)
  spi.open(0,0)
  spi.max_speed_hz = 10000 
  channel_seven = spi.xfer2([180,0])
  spi.close()

  print "ch6 array:{}".format(channel_six)
  print "ch7 array:{}".format(channel_seven)

  six_data = (channel_six[0]<<8) + channel_six[1]
  print "ch6:{}".format(six_data)
  sev_data = (channel_seven[0]<<8) + channel_seven[1]
  print "ch6:{}".format(sev_data)

  print "ch6 in Volts:{}".format(ConvertVolts(six_data,4))
  print "ch7 in Volts: {}".format(ConvertVolts(sev_data,4))
  return_six data
```

Below is a piscope graph of SCK, MISO, MOSI and CE0. 
[image]

The Data out is correct but the order is wrong. Channel 6 should be 2.5V and Channel 7 should be 0V. I guess I could swap them around but I wanted to know what exactly is going on.

Why do the values get swapped? 
How do I edit my code so the values come out the way I want (swapped)? 
Is there a way to add a small delay so they don't affect each other?

I tried a similar thing with pigpio and the results were similar.

Comment: As a matter of interest why do you keep opening and closing SPI?  It would be normal to open once at the start of the program and close once at the end.

Comment: @joan I thought it would help solve the problem. I thought that the two SPI transfers were interfering so I though closing and opening it would solve it

Comment: I'm going to guess you are misinterpreting the results.  I haven't looked carefully at the datasheet but a cursory read leaves me confused.  If the chip returns repeatable results I'd spend more time looking at the datasheet.

Comment: @joan thanks! COuld you explain what you mean by repeatable results?

Comment: Try inputting three different voltages on a channel (say 0, middle, max).  Do you get consistent but different readings for each voltage.  That implies the processing chain of ADC->Pi is working, and sort of implies your interpretation of the readings is wrong.

Comment: Just tried 3.3V,2.5V, 0V it consistently returns approximately 0V, 3.3V,2.5V so I'm getting the order wrong but not quite sure why. It works perfectly with one channel. Just trying to figure out what part of my interpretation is wrong.